# transforming scale_colour_gradient to log2 space in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

If I have a plot in ggplot2 where the value plotted is transformed into log2 but is also used as a colour value, as in:

```
geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=y)) + scale_y_continuous(trans=scales.log2_trans()) + scale_colour_gradient()
```

how can I make `scale_colour_gradient` show the values in log2 (not just log) scale as well? The raw `y` values in the dataframe are unlogged. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use transformations also inside `scale_colour_gradient()` the same way as in `scale_y_continuous()`.

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)
library(scales)
ggplot(df)+geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=y)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans()) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(trans=log2_trans())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, follow up q: if I want to change the `limits=` of `y`s colour gradient now, do I use the log values or the natural values?

Comment: @user248237dfsf You use natural values - transformation is done on the limits by trans=

Comment: Using this transrform results in `Error in inherits(x, "trans") : could not find function "log2_trans"`. You now need, `trans="log10"`

Comment: @notconfusing Did add `library(scales)` - for me this works without problems.